# Pair deduplication on CUDA

Tags: duplicates, cuda, gpu, thrust

I have a data structure already running on CUDA and collect the data as below:

```
struct SearchDataOnDevice
{
    size_t npair;
    int * id1;
    int * id2;
};
```

I'd like to remove the duplicated id pair w/ and w/o an option called `same_id_src`, when `same_id_src` is `true`, `<0, 5>` and `<5, 0>` are duplicated and `<5, 0>` should be removed. when `same_id_src` is `false`, both pairs should be kept.

I am new to CUDA and the Thrust library, can anyone help with a quick hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

1. sort the ID pairs, to bring "like" pairs together (`thrust::sort`)
2. identify which pairs to keep, based on comparing adjacent pairs. Put results in a stencil array (`thrust::transform`)
3. based on the stencil array, use `thrust::copy_if` to perform stream compaction on the sorted pairs to produce the deduplicated result

The need to handle the cases where e.g. `<0 5>` and `<5 0>` are considered "identical" or not, is handled via modification to the sort functor, as well as modification to the transform functor.  In the sort functor case, we reorder, for comparison purposes, each pair such that the lower ID appears first in the pair.  We must arrange the sort functor carefully, so that the case of `<0 5>` is chosen preferentially over the case of `<5 0>`, when the special condition is true.

Here is an example:

```
# cat t76.cu
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct my_sort_functor
{
  bool same_id_src;
  my_sort_functor(bool _same_id_src) : same_id_src(_same_id_src) {};
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2){
    int t1a = thrust::get<0>(t1);
    int t1b = thrust::get<1>(t1);
    int t2a = thrust::get<0>(t2);
    int t2b = thrust::get<1>(t2);
    if (same_id_src) {//need to possibly reorder each pair for testing
      bool t1s = (t1a > t1b);
      bool t2s = (t2a > t2b);
      // sort on smaller id first
      if ((t1s?t1b:t1a) < (t2s?t2b:t2a)) return true;
      if ((t1s?t1b:t1a) > (t2s?t2b:t2a)) return false;
      // then sort on larger id
      if ((t1s?t1a:t1b) < (t2s?t2a:t2b)) return true;
      if ((t1s?t1a:t1b) > (t2s?t2a:t2b)) return false;
      // then sort based on the equality case
      // we prefer to choose <0,5> over <5,0>
      // so order that one first
      return !t1s;}
    else { // no reordering of pairs
      // sort on first id
      if (t1a < t2a) return true;
      if (t1a > t2a) return false;
      // sort on second id
      if (t1b < t2b) return true;
      return false;}
    }
};

struct my_transform_functor
{
  bool same_id_src;
  my_transform_functor(bool _same_id_src) : same_id_src(_same_id_src) {};
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2){
    if ((thrust::get<0>(t1) == thrust::get<0>(t2)) && (thrust::get<1>(t1) == thrust::get<1>(t2))) return false;
    if (same_id_src)
      if ((thrust::get<0>(t1) == thrust::get<1>(t2)) && (thrust::get<1>(t1) == thrust::get<0>(t2))) return false;
    return true;
    }
};

struct my_copy_predicate
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(bool t) { return t;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  // data setup
  int d1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
  int d2[] = {5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5};
  bool same_id_src = true;
  if (argc > 1) same_id_src = false;
  size_t npair = sizeof(d1)/sizeof(d1[0]);
  int *id1, *id2;
  cudaMalloc(&id1, sizeof(d1));
  cudaMalloc(&id2, sizeof(d1));
  cudaMemcpy(id1, d1, sizeof(d1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(id2, d2, sizeof(d1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  auto dp_id1 = thrust::device_ptr<int>(id1);
  auto dp_id2 = thrust::device_ptr<int>(id2);
  auto dzip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dp_id1, dp_id2));
  thrust::device_vector<bool> stencil(npair, true);
  thrust::device_vector<int> r1(npair);
  thrust::device_vector<int> r2(npair);
  auto rzip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(r1.begin(), r2.begin()));
  // step 1: sort
  thrust::sort(dzip, dzip+npair, my_sort_functor(same_id_src));
  // step 2: mark pairs to be kept in stencil
  thrust::transform(dzip, dzip+npair-1, dzip+1,  stencil.begin()+1, my_transform_functor(same_id_src));
  // step 3: copy if, using stencil
  int rsize = thrust::copy_if(dzip, dzip+npair, stencil.begin(), rzip, my_copy_predicate()) - rzip;
  // display result
  thrust::copy_n(r1.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(r2.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
# nvcc -o t76 t76.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t76
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0 1 4 3
5 2 1 2
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
# compute-sanitizer ./t76 1
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0 1 2 3 4 5
5 2 1 2 1 0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
#
```

When we don't specify a command-line argument, the special case is considered to be true, and additional "duplicates" are removed.  When we do specify a command-line argument, the special case is considered to be false.

EDIT: Working off a comment from paleonix below, we can improve the above implementation by replacing steps 2 and 3 with a call to `thrust::unique_copy`, which is also a stream compaction operation.  The sort process remains unchanged, and only a slight change is made to our previous transform functor, to make it usable for the `unique_copy` operation:

```
# cat t76.cu
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct my_sort_functor
{
  bool same_id_src;
  my_sort_functor(bool _same_id_src) : same_id_src(_same_id_src) {};
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2){
    int t1a = thrust::get<0>(t1);
    int t1b = thrust::get<1>(t1);
    int t2a = thrust::get<0>(t2);
    int t2b = thrust::get<1>(t2);
    if (same_id_src) {//need to possibly reorder each pair for testing
      bool t1s = (t1a > t1b);
      bool t2s = (t2a > t2b);
      // sort on smaller id first
      if ((t1s?t1b:t1a) < (t2s?t2b:t2a)) return true;
      if ((t1s?t1b:t1a) > (t2s?t2b:t2a)) return false;
      // then sort on larger id
      if ((t1s?t1a:t1b) < (t2s?t2a:t2b)) return true;
      if ((t1s?t1a:t1b) > (t2s?t2a:t2b)) return false;
      // then sort based on the equality case
      // we prefer to choose <0,5> over <5,0>
      // so order that one first
      return !t1s;}
    else { // no reordering of pairs
      // sort on first id
      if (t1a < t2a) return true;
      if (t1a > t2a) return false;
      // sort on second id
      if (t1b < t2b) return true;
      return false;}
    }
};

struct my_transform_functor
{
  bool same_id_src;
  my_transform_functor(bool _same_id_src) : same_id_src(_same_id_src) {};
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2){
    if ((thrust::get<0>(t1) == thrust::get<0>(t2)) && (thrust::get<1>(t1) == thrust::get<1>(t2))) return true;
    if (same_id_src)
      if ((thrust::get<0>(t1) == thrust::get<1>(t2)) && (thrust::get<1>(t1) == thrust::get<0>(t2))) return true;
    return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  // data setup
  int d1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
  int d2[] = {5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5};
  bool same_id_src = true;
  if (argc > 1) same_id_src = false;
  size_t npair = sizeof(d1)/sizeof(d1[0]);
  int *id1, *id2;
  cudaMalloc(&id1, sizeof(d1));
  cudaMalloc(&id2, sizeof(d1));
  cudaMemcpy(id1, d1, sizeof(d1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(id2, d2, sizeof(d1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  auto dp_id1 = thrust::device_ptr<int>(id1);
  auto dp_id2 = thrust::device_ptr<int>(id2);
  auto dzip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dp_id1, dp_id2));
  thrust::device_vector<int> r1(npair);
  thrust::device_vector<int> r2(npair);
  auto rzip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(r1.begin(), r2.begin()));
  // step 1: sort
  thrust::sort(dzip, dzip+npair, my_sort_functor(same_id_src));
  // step 2: copy unique elements
  int rsize = thrust::unique_copy(dzip, dzip+npair, rzip, my_transform_functor(same_id_src)) - rzip;
  // display result
  thrust::copy_n(r1.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(r2.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
# nvcc -o t76 t76.cu
# ./t76
0 1 4 3
5 2 1 2
# ./t76 1
0 1 2 3 4 5
5 2 1 2 1 0
#
```

Comment: I think using `thrust::unique` or `thrust::unique_copy` with custom comparators would be even more elegant.

Comment: Yes, it would probably allow steps 2 and 3 to be reduced to a single step.  The sorting is still needed and arranging the sort functor is where the real effort is, in my view.

Comment: I'm wondering if sorting each pair in a transform might be more performant than having such a complicated comparator. If I remember correctly Thrust even comes with a builtin comparator for `thrust::tuple` s.t. one doesn't need to specify one at all in that case. The implementation of `unique` for the CUDA backend also seems to be relatively involved, so I would hope that it is faster than your version (which could also be sped up using a `transform_iterator` for the stencil).

Comment: Nowhere did I state that what I offered was the most performant approach possible. I can't imagine ever making such a claim.   So there may be more performant approaches than anything I post on SO. I don't really understand your statement about sorting each pair (I think that is what I am doing) and I certainly wouldn't want to add extra global loads and stores.  Feel free to post an answer of your own.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to discredit your answer, just pondering it. You are right that the complicated comparator is the better choice as the prior transform would not change the global memory access by the sort which is the bottleneck. For such cases I would love an out-of-place sort s.t. one can fuse an input transform. As long as OP doesn't ask for them specifically, I don't think that either using `unique_copy` or a transform iterator for the stencil are substantial enough changes from your code to substantiate their own answer. Edit: Thanks for adding `unique_copy`!

Comment: It used to be the conventional wisdom with thrust that if you presented a sort problem that could fit the radix-sort model, it would be substantially faster than the alternate merge sort implementation, and usually providing a sort functor of any kind dropped you into the merge sort case.  So it's possible that by reordering the pairs at the input to the sort operation, rather than in the functor as I am doing, might be faster.  Yes, sort knows how to order tuples "natively" but I don't happen to know if that affects the  merge-vs.-radix decision.  I guess that is what you are pointing out.

Comment: It's also not obvious to me how to handle the special case (preferring `<0 5>` over `<5 0>`) if we reorder pairs at input to the sort, in hopes of avoiding the use of a functor, in hopes of taking advantage of radix sort (if that is even applicable to the tuple case).

Comment: Ah, I'm just talking about tha special case. By ordering the pairs upfront, both are `<0 5>`. And yeah, it wont use radix sort if I interpret [`can_use_primitive_sort`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cccl/blob/abe6d1cf882205eaef064103c0e8bc653f3ee951/thrust/thrust/system/cuda/detail/sort.h#L396-L401) and [`is_arithmetic`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cccl/blob/abe6d1cf882205eaef064103c0e8bc653f3ee951/thrust/thrust/detail/type_traits.h#L81-L85) correctly.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I am wondering how to do the compaction if the input data id1 and id2 contain garbage values like 354643213132 in those memory addresses.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that. If you want to do something meaningfull, you need to initialize your memory first.

Comment: I know, let's say all the garbage values are initialized to -1, could I compact the data during a single sort and unique call?

Comment: @holmessh In the first solution using `copy_if` it should then be easy to remove them from the stencil. I.e. in that case `unique` isn't the right algorithm anymore.

Comment: @holmessh In theory you could also find the partition point between real pairs and garbage ones using a binary search and then only do `unique` on the real pairs, but I think `copy_if` with a `transform_iterator` for the stencil is the better solution.